# How do I get rid of multiple H1's on homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, header, cms-block, widgets

I am relatively new to Magento with past experience of WordPress of few years. I'm trying to get rid of the multiple H1s on the homepage of a new client.

**sobefurniture.com**

The developer coded the homepage with `cms-block` as follows:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/popular_cats.phtml"}}
```

The html code (without <> symbols) for it is as follows...

```
div class="homebannner_slider"

img id="e3t3aWRnZXQgdHlwZT0iY21zL3dpZGdldF9ibG9jayIgdGVtcGxhdGU9ImNtcy93aWRnZXQvc3RhdGljX2Jsb2NrL2RlZmF1bHQucGh0bWwiIGJsb2NrX2lkPSJhcndfc2ViaWFuX2hvbWVfZnVybml0dXJlX2Jsb2NrX2Jhbm5lcl8xIn19" title="{widget type=&quot;cms/widget_block&quot; template=&quot;cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml&quot; block_id=&quot;arw_sebian_home_furniture_block_banner_1&quot;}" alt="" src="https://www.sobefurniture.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/widget/cms__widget_block.gif" /
/div

div class="popular_cat_main">&nbsp;{{block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/popular_cats.phtml"}}
/div

<iv class="cat_main"
img id="e3t3aWRnZXQgdHlwZT0iY21zL3dpZGdldF9ibG9jayIgdGVtcGxhdGU9ImNtcy93aWRnZXQvc3RhdGljX2Jsb2NrL2RlZmF1bHQucGh0bWwiIGJsb2NrX2lkPSJhcndfc2ViaWFuX2hvbWVfZnVybml0dXJlX2Jsb2NrX3BhcmFsbGF4X2JhY2tncm91bmQifX0-" title="{widget type=&quot;cms/widget_block&quot; template=&quot;cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml&quot; block_id=&quot;arw_sebian_home_furniture_block_parallax_background&quot;}" alt="" src="https://www.sobefurniture.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/widget/cms__widget_block.gif" /
/div

div class="cat_main">&nbsp;/div

div class="cat_main">&nbsp;/div

div class="cat_main"
script type="text/javascript"
// ![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ arexworks.Frontend.fixSlider();})
// ]]
/script
/div
```

I started out sifting through the static blocks looking for any that would match catalog, product, product_new and there are over 110 enabled (i think many are for possible styles of the template that were not used) and none seem to fit and I can't figure out how to get insight on where to find the right match.

I also have ftp access if this is easier but was unable to locate the right file path to find... `catalog/product/popular_cats.phtml`

I just want to find where I can adjust the inline style or css to make the h1 look the same while shifting it to an h3 or title tag or something less impactful to SEO.

Any insights or help or tips or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the path of this block: `{{block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/popular_cats.phtml"}}`, you have to go to :

```
app/design/frontend/{yourCurrentPackage}/{yourCurrentTheme}/template/catalog/product/popular_cats.phtml
```

Now you have your template, you can customise it like you cant, if you want to add some css classes you have to do this:

```
<div class="my_popular_cats"> // you add this class
    ... // here your current code
    <h1>My super title</h1> // just an exmple
    <h3>My second title</h3> // just an exmple
</div>
```

To add your **css**, go to : `skin/frontend/{yourCurrentPackage}/{yourCurrentTheme}/css/style.css`, then :

```
.my_popular_cats h1{
    color:#eaeaea;
    padding:4px;
}

.my_popular_cats h2{
    color:#000;
    padding:4px;
}
```

Save and refresh you cache : `admin->system->cache manager->purge cache`.

Comment: Thank You! That top ftp path was exactly what I needed to find the file I wanted to edit.

Comment: you're welcome, please accept the answer